# Mobile design - price range pick

Tags: design-patterns, best-practice, price-range, datepicker

Im trying to improve UX of mobile version of our loan website and I have hard times figuring how to improve price range and day picker. I am enclosing you what I have so far and would like to improve.

Are you familiar with any alternative solutions that might work better on mobile devices?

[image]

Comment: I like it. Can you lend me some money?

Comment: I would change the appearance of the scale since it looks like a ruler, otherwise i like it.

Answer (score 1):

If clicking on the center number in the **price** field(and on the **due** field as well) allows the user to type in the number manually, then you're good.

You could also consider the *vertical* wheel view/picker as I have come across it more often than the horizontal one.

Answer (score 0):

Shreyas' suggestion is spot on.

The scale "scroll to select" mechanic is really cool looking and it works most of the time. However ensure there are alternate ways of inputing a value.

You could have users with motor disabilities, parkinsons, huge thumbs etc. So you need to make sure those users are not alienated by a difficult mechanic.

I would even be tempted to suggest you abandon the slider idea altogether and go with two simple, legible and touch friendly input fields that will allow users to insert values as accurately as they need to.

Especially considering this is a lending option and not a game, it can be quite important for someone to be able to enter the correct value of the money they need.